# Bot vs Rest Based Calls - Media Wiki

Tags: mediawiki

What's the difference between a bot on MediaWiki vs using the Rest Based api to do the operations?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you mean. Could you clarify? The MediaWiki API is not very RESTful and bots can use it.

Comment: What I mean is , why would I write a mediawiki bot ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You would write a bot if you wanted to do some automated task on some wiki. For examples, you can look at the myriad of bots on the English Wikipedia.

Comment: why can't I do the same things via media wiki api ? I just found a link to the the rest based API for mediawiki http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API/Tutorial I'm not sure when you say Media wiki is not very RESTful , what are you exactly referring to.

Comment: Please try to clarify your question -- it's hard to guess what you're trying to ask here. It might help if you provided an example of a specific task that you'd like to accomplish using either a bot or the MediaWiki API.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what a BOT is in a mediawiki world and what it can do?

Comment: Does [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot) answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

If by "bot" you mean screen-scraping, such "bots" are severely discouraged and we developers don't make any guarantee that screen-scraping will work reliably, i.e. HTML output can drastically change at any moment without any prior notice. On the other hand, MediaWiki's web API is designed with stability in mind - in addition to other benefits such as machine-readable output (ol' good JSON is much easier to parse than tag soup) and better performance (we don't spend server resources on sking rendering, you don't spend bandwidth on receiving it).

Comment: Media Wiki Bots are different from screen scraping....

Comment: +1 for at least trying to guess what this question might be about (and for providing generally good advice).